# run external program and exit from calling program

Tags: vb.net, external

n the closing procedure of a program (just before running Application.exit) I need to run an external program to pass a parameter and exit the calling program.
The program called (FilmDB_Update.exe) has the task of overwriting the main program or a dll library.
I tried to use the "process.start" technique, but apparently, the calling program remains in use and does not allow me to overwrite it.
This is the code that I write:

```
Private Sub AggiornaPgm()
    Dim ws_file As String = "FilmDB_Update.exe"
    Dim ws_proc_param As String = """" + ws_working_path + """ " + ws_temp_path
    Dim ws_fullPath As String = Path.Combine(ws_temp_path, ws_file)

    If File.Exists(ws_fullPath) Then

        File.Copy(ws_fullPath, ws_file, True)
    End If

    Dim proc As New System.Diagnostics.Process()
    proc = Process.Start(ws_file, ws_proc_param)
End Sub
```

I wanted to try using the shell command, but I can not pass the parameters to the called program.
Does any of you have any other ideas about it?
Thank you

Marcello

As Ahmed suggested, I added the test for the calling process to the program called.

```
    p = Process.GetProcessesByName(ws_calling_pgm)
    While p.Count > 0

        Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
        p = Process.GetProcessesByName(ws_calling_pgm)
    End While

    p = Nothing
```

When I exit the While loop, the calling process is terminated. I do not understand why, despite the process no longer exists, the main program is still in use.

Comment: Make sure you close the file in your main program before calling the external program that will update it.

Comment: In the post, erroneously, I did not specify that one of the files to be updated is the calling program itself.
In practice I'm building a system to distribute the program update on different PCs without the need for manual intervention on each PC.

Comment: Are you the developer of the second program? If so, you can make it check if (and wait until) the process of the first program is exited. If not, then there's no guarantee that the first program will be exited by the time the second one tries to access its files. In this case, you might consider creating a temp batch file that waits a few seconds, starts the process and then deletes itself.

Comment: Yes, I'm the developer of both programs. 
I try to change the second program as you advised me. To avoid sending the CPU 100% waiting for the first program to close, just use the thread.sleep function in the waiting loop? Thanks